# How do I get information from a $dialog controller to any other controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am opening Dialogs that can be minimized, brought-back, edited at any time and finally submitted. What I'm trying to do might be more than just a dialog but I'm hoping that it can work out.

Right now I have it so that I can summon my dialog, pre-populate it with existing data, edit and submit. My major problem right now is that I have no idea how to send the final, possibly edited data to another controller in my client.

$scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit doesn't appear to be working.. The injected controller resides outside of the others somehow?

This is how I'm creating my dialog:

```
$scope.openDialog = function(index){
    var html = $scope.buildHTML(index);

    var opts = {
        resizeable: true,
        backdrop: false,
        handle: ".modal-header",
        template: html,
        controller: 'OpenItemCtrl',
        resolve: {
            itemModel: function() {              
                return $scope.item[index];
            }
        }
    };

    var d = $dialog.dialog(opts);
    d.open().then(function() {
        // Right here I can determine that a dialog has closed.
        alert(index);
    });
};
```

And this is my controller:

```
function OpenItemCtrl($scope, dialog, itemModel) {
    $scope.item= {};

    for(key in itemModel) {
        $scope.item[key] = itemModel[key];
    }

    $scope.close = function(qty, src, price){
        // I need to get these edited variables back 
        // into my controller classes somehow...
        $scope.$emit("ItemFinalized", {msg:$scope.item});
        $scope.$broadcast("ItemFinalized", {msg:$scope.item});
        dialog.close();
    };
}
```

How can I get my final data back into my controller hierarchy so I can pass them around as I need to?

Comment: Are you using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ui.bootstrap if so they have an example with the dialog that uses a promise to return data when it's closed.

Comment: Also this problem used to happen in AS3 too with it's PopUpManager and title window classes etc. I think it's probably a similar issue when attempting to use emit/broadcast as you would run into with AS3 in that the pop ups and modals have a parent that is outside of the normal hierarchy of display objects (I'm sure in this case the modal is part of the DOM, but perhaps in a location that is a sibling to your other controllers).

Comment: Thank you, it was half staring me in the face but I didn't see it :P I am able to hand the JSON I was going to emit/broadcast back through the promise so I have it as well :) Now all I need to figure out is how to make them draggable and I'm set!

Comment: No problem glad any time I can actually answer an Angular question and happened to just be working with the dialog :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long and short of it, you call the dialog services dialog method it returns a promise, when that promise is resolved a function is called that is passed the data that is passed to the dialog close call in the dialog's controller.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog

```
$scope.opts = {
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    backdropClick: true,
    template:  t, // OR: templateUrl: 'path/to/view.html',
    controller: 'TestDialogController'
  };

$scope.openDialog = function(){
    var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
    d.open().then(function(result){
      if(result)
      {
        alert('dialog closed with result: ' + result);
      }
    });
  };


// the dialog is injected in the specified controller
function TestDialogController($scope, dialog){
  $scope.close = function(result){
    dialog.close(result);
  };
}
```