# Filter module from external html file on Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to filter a list (inside list.html) using:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events | filter:filter | orderBy:order">
```

And I have a filter dialog inside my ListController

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$dialog', function($scope,$dialog) {
  $scope.filterDialog = function() {
      var dlg = $dialog.dialog({
          templateUrl: 'pages/filter.html',
          controller: 'FilterController'
      });
  };

}])
```

and filter.html contains:

```
<form id="filter-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter</legend>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="filter.description">
    <div id="sort_section">
        <label>Sort By:</label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="sort_by" value="time" ng-model="order.time" ng-checked="true" /> Time
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="sort_by" value="distance" ng-model="order.name" /> Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="close(filter,order)">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

It doesn't seem to bind with the list and thus, the list doesn't filter.
What am I missing here?

**Update** 
I changed the code above (added parameters to the ng-click="close()" call), 
 and 
I've noticed that only when I delete the `type="radio"`
part, I can get the "order".

**Update** 
It's the `ng-checked="true"` piece, once removed I got the filter piece just fine.

Comment: I think your `ng-model="order.*"` is bound to the FilterController, not the controller of `<div ng-repeat`

Comment: how do I bind it to the ListController?

Comment: Can you include your ListController code ?

Comment: I suggest you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552505/how-do-i-get-information-from-a-dialog-controller-to-any-other-controller , I think it is what you need

Comment: sadly didn't solve my problem, I can display the information in the controller, but it seems that I'm still not getting the information from "order" (due to type="radio"), plus the filtering is still not working.

Comment: It should work, please provide a complete and testable example, preferably with an online platform like JSFiddle, so we can hack it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different controllers here :ListController and FilterController

The "filter" that you are trying to use belongs to scope of FilterController, and you cant access it directly in ListController.

So you will need a service which will hold the "filter" so we can use it in both controllers:

### Service.js

```
app.factory('filterData', function() {
  var filter = {        
    name: "abc"
  };    
  return filter;
});
```

Use this in both controllers

### ListController

```
app.controller('ListController', function($scope, filterData) {
  $scope.filter = filterData;
});
```

### FilterController

```
app.controller('FilterController', function($scope, filterData) {
  $scope.filter = filterData;
});
```